# How do I fix mime type errors for Xampp?

Tags: drupal, xampp

I've recently installed Xampp on a localhost and installed a Drupal installation on it. Now after moving (fresh install of Xampp) it to my server I'm receiving MIME type errors (See image)

This problem occurs on every browser I've tried so I am assuming the issue resides within my Xampp installation, but all info I can find about this matter or people who have/had the same seems unfinished.

Here a screenshot of my console log in Google Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be some issue with the aggregation. At least that's what the guys over here try: https://www.drupal.org/project/jstools/issues/72561#comment-12566682

So try disabling aggregation for javascript and css and see if that works. If so, we can investigate further, why it matters. (I wouldn't leave aggregation turned off on a production site...)